# Materialize css select box broken with large number of options

Tags: angular, materialize

I am using Materialize select box and I have around 50000 options to show. How can I achieve virtual scrolling for select box?
When I am simply adding 50000 options then page is not responsive as there are so many options in DOM at a time.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If Materialize.css documentation does not show any infinite scrolling feature, and it does not seem to, then it probably does not exist, and you'll have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you add such number of elements to HTML, yes, it will be very slow. So I think the best would be to change the input field type. You could try:

- An autocomplete field, which will show some results after entering few characters
- Your custom selector (probably some popup dialog) with a possibility to search for the value user wants. For example if searching for a car model, you would have a vendor select box and a year range. Then you can display a list of matching options to pick.
- Add pagination to the list of options. But this is not used often.